# Find the vector equation of a line passing through point A perpendicular to line AB

Tags: vector-spaces

'Points A and B have coordinates (4,1) and (2,-5) respectively. Find a vector equation for the line which passes through the point A (only the point A), and which is perpendicular to the line AB.'

Hello!
I need help with this question regarding vectors. I have worked with the formula for a position vector as follows: r= p+t(q-p) where the q and p represent the vectors/points.. However, I do not seem to manage to get to the textbook answer: (4+3t)i+(1-t)j. I have calculated the following:
Vector of AB: B-A which equals to (-2,-6), but when I use this in the given formula with (4,1) it doesn't seem right. I am also aware that since it is perpendicular the dot product = 0 
But when computing these (4,1)•(-2,-6) it doesn't equal to zero, but to -4. I have read somewhere that a+b=-a+b regarding this kind of relations, but I am missing out on something here.. This is supposed to be fairly easy as it is one of the first questions.. But I have been stuck for quite some time. Thanks for any help!

Comment: A vector perpendicular to (a, b) is (-b, a) since their dot product is 0. You found the direction of the line between A and B. What is the direction of the line perpendilcular to it?

Answer (score 0):

- search for a line of the form A+t*R, where R is perpendicular to the line AB.
- A vektor is perpendicular to AB when its perpendicular to A-B.
- The vector (x,y) is perpendicular to (y,-x).

You should be able to do it now.